# Apache Virtualhost config for Flask

Tags: apache, flask, virtualhost

I have my website in PHP and apache server at 192.168.0.1

I have to run a Python script, so I installed Flask and mod_wsgi for apache.
I want that browsing 192.168.0.1 it responds with the website, while browsing 192.168.0.1/run it runs my Python script.
How do I configure the Virtualhost file?
I wrote this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  DocumentRoot "D:\web\default"
  <Directory "D:\web\default">
    AllowOverride None
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:\code\script"
  WSGIScriptAlias /run "D:\code\script\config\process.wsgi"
  <Directory "D:\code\script\config">
    AllowOverride None
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It works ok for the website, while it answers "The requested URL was not found on this server." to 192.168.0.1/run

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
  DocumentRoot "D:\web\default"   
  <Directory "D:\web\default">
    AllowOverride None
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted   
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias /run "D:\code\script\config\process.wsgi"   
  <Directory "D:\code\script\config">
    AllowOverride None
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted   
  </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope that the missing `DocumentRoot "D:\code\script"` doesn't affect the Python script execution